# Merge 2 RegEx's into 1 without using a pipe

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been messing about with RegEx's and was wondering if there was a good way to actually "merge" them together, but without just using a pipe to indicate an OR scenario... I have scribbled something basic like this:

```
var v1 = '\\d{3}\\w{1}';
var v2 = '\\d{10}\\w{1}';

var regex = [];

for(var i = 0; i < v1.length; i += 2) {
    if((v1[i] + v1[i + 1]) == (v2[i] + v2[i + 1])) {
        var higher = v1[i + 3] > v2[i + 3] ? v1[i + 3] : v2[i + 3];
        var lower = v1[i + 3] < v2[i + 3] ? v1[i + 3] : v2[i + 3];
        regex += v1[i] + v1[i + 1] + '{' + lower + ',' + higher + '}';
    }
}

console.log(regex);
```

And was wondering if anyone else had seen something that would work for me or if they had any ideas... without expanding my code by a large amount this will only work when the numbers are 1 digit long only.

Comment: So you want `\d{3}\w{1}` and `\d{10}\w{1}` become `\d{3,10}\w{1}`?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini that's correct :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use a conditional like:

```
\\d{3}\\d{7}?\\w
```

This effectively handles both of your scenarios by making the second sequence of seven digits optional. It is important to note that the \w on the end could also be a digit because the character class that \w is short for allows all letters and digits, as well as the underscore character.

One problem would be if your data won't be specifically 4 characters or 11 characters long. Because you're not looking for boundaries or some kind of delimiting character in here, you could be matching the middle of a string of characters where three or seven digits just happen to exist right next to each other.

If you know that your data will be only 4 or 11 characters long, no problem! but I'd recommend "anchoring" your regex somewhere so that you don't get into the problem I just mentioned. you can use ^ and $ to signify start and end of a string or use \b, \s, \W, or \D or something if you have something reliably on the outside of the important data.

Comment: `\d{3}\d{7}?\w{1}` is **not** equivalent to `\d{3,10}\w{1}`. The first does not accept `1234a`.

Comment: That's correct, it is not the same as `\d{3,10}` the OP asked about making the two regular expressions merge into one not using an or, what you've provided is not that. The expression you provided allows for any number of digits between (and including) 3 and 10 followed by a \w. On the other hand, mine exactly matches the two regular expressions provided in the original post because it matches only 3 or 10 digits followed by a \w, which is what the two regular expressions in the original post did.